# Strong tournaments

Tags: graph-theory

Let $T$ be a strong tournament, and let $N=v_1v_2 \cdots v_n$ be an enumeration of $V(T)$. Let $C$ be a circuit in $T$. We define $i_N(C)=|\{(v_i,v_j) \in E(C); i>j\}|$. Suppose that $N$ is chosen in such a way that $i_N(C_1)+ \cdots + i_N(C_t)$ is minimum, where $C_1, \cdots, C_t$ are all the circuits of $T$.

Prove that $\forall i$ such that $1 \le i \le n-1$, $(v_i,v_{i+1}) \in E(T)$ and that $(v_n,v_1) \in E(T)$.

**My attempt:**

I already proved that $\forall i$ such that $1 \le i \le n-1$ we have $(v_i,v_{i+1})\in E(T)$.

I first assumed that $(v_i,v_{i+1}) \not \in E(T)$, and this gives that $(v_{i+1},v_{i})\in E(T)$, so I took the enumeration $N'=v_1 \cdots v_{i-1}v_{i+1}v_iv_{i+2} \cdots v_n$, and proved that $i_{N'}(C_1)+ \cdots + i_{N'}(C_t)< i_N(C_1)+ \cdots + i_N(C_t)$, which is a contradiction.

But for proving $(v_n,v_1) \in E(T)$ I supposed that $(v_1,v_n) \in E(T)$ and tried to take the enumeration $N''=v_nv_1\cdots v_{n-1}$ but I wasn't able to get to a contradiction, since to get to a contradiction from this enumeration I must be sure that the number of forward edges going to $v_n$ was less than that of the backward edges from $v_n$ in the first enumeration, can I prove this?Or do I take 2 cases if the number of forward edges was less or more than that of the  backward edges? Or is there another enumeration that can finish it?

Please help, and thanks in advance.

Comment: I feel like I don't understand something.  Suppose that $(v_i, v_{i+1})\notin E(T).$  Doesn't reversing them in the enumeration give $i_{E'}(C_1)+ \cdots + i_{E'}(C_t)> i_E(C_1)+ \cdots + i_E(C_t)?$

Comment: to clarify strong means strongly connected? then I think I see the point your optimum should be completely a DAG except for one edge from v_n to v_1

Comment: @saulspatz the number of backward edges in $E'$ is the same as in $E$ **except** for the edge $(v_{i+1},v_i)$ it was backward with respect to $E$ and it is forward with respect to $E'$, so the number of backward edges decreased by $1$ and thats the contradiction

Comment: @FareedAF   thats a very strange definition of tournament   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament_(graph_theory)

Comment: Your definition seems to count forward edges, not backward edges, though.   Also, in your previous comment, I think you reversed the meanings ot tournament and strong.

Comment: Yes yes I am so sorry I reversed them @Hao Sun, I mean by **tournament** that for $x,y∈T$, then $(x,y)∈E(T)$ or $(y,x)∈E(T)$, and by **strong** that for all $x,y∈T$ then there exist an $xy$-directed path.

Comment: @saulspatz I don't understand where you see it counting forward edges, as mentioned above, $i_E(C)=|\{(v_i,v_j) \in E(C); i>j\}|$. So for example $(v_3,v_2)$ is counted in $i_E(C)$ since $3>2$ (and that is a backward edge) and $(v_3,v_6)$ is not counted because $3 \not \gt 6$ (and that is a forward edge) so I think that the definition is correct.

Comment: Okay, I see that I misread it.

Comment: @bof do you have an answer to my question please? Or do you someone who might have the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $(v_n,v_1)\not\in E$ then consider the enumeration $N'=(v_2,v_3,\cdots,v_{n-1},v_1,v_n)$. It is easy to see that for any circuit $C$ such that $(v_1,v_n)\not\in E(C)$ we have $i_N(C)=i_{N'}(C)$. For any circuit $C$ such that $(v_1,v_n)\in E(C)$ (and there is one since $T$ is strong) we get $i_{N'}(C)=i_N(C)-1$, contradicting our assumption on $N$.

Answer (score -1):

hmm I think what you can do is if $v_1 v_n$ is directed towards $v_n$, then consider reversing it and all other backwards arcs
Consider a circuit in this digraph $T'$ (all edges forward except $v_1,v_n$ ) each such circuit consists of a path $P$ from $v_1$ to $v_n$  and back from $v_n$ to $v_1$
Let $Q$ be a path from $v_n$ to $v_1$ in $T$
If $P$ consists not entirely of edges directed backwards in $T$, then $P \cup Q$ is a closed walk  in $T$ where some edges appear only once and hence contains a cycle.
Otherwise$ P \cup v_1v_n$ is a cycle in $T$
Also there is at least 1 path $P$ which uses 2 backward edges of $T$
and thus the tournament $T'$ has smaller value contradiction

Comment: Consider the edges $(v_2,v_3), (v_3,v_5)$ and $(v_5,v_2)$. Can you find an enumeration such that all the edges are forward ?!

Comment: @FareedAF by forward I mean directed from the smaller vertex to the larger I claim if T has v_1 v_n directed as such then T has larger objective than  directing all edges except v_n v_1 towards the larger vertex which I call T'